# JavaScript access JSON message

Tags: javascript, json, string

i found a lot of ways to Access JSON data in JavaScript but None of them seems to be working (for me):

```
ws.onmessage = function(msg) {
    var stringMsg = msg.data.toString();
    stringMsg = '\''+ stringMsg + '\''
    console.log(stringMsg);
    var jsonMsg = JSON.parse(stringMsg);
    alert(jsonMsg.sensorID);
    var outputtextarea = document.getElementById("outputtext");
    outputtextarea.value += (msg.data + "\n");
    outputtextarea.scrollTop = outputtextarea.scrollHeight;
}
```

The Console Output Displays this:

```
'{"sensorID": "kali1", "msgValue": "AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:BLA!Box BLA WLAN 4000", "msgType": "unknown SSID"}'
```

and the Parser puts out this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

But the String seems to be valid JSON (thats what i think and all the JSON-Validators i used online)

I also tried to Access my message directly with:

```
alert(msg.sensorID)
alert(msg.data.sensorID)
```

These Popups just Display "undefined"

P.S. I dont want to convert the JSON to a string and back, this is just for debugging

Comment: `alter()`? What's that?

Comment: You shouldn't have ' around the string when parsing it.

Comment: Get rid of the quotes around the stringMsg. Just use msg.data (or msg.data.toString()) instead. It's already a valid JSON string.

Comment: I suspect you mean alert rather than alter.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> stringMsg = '\''+ stringMsg + '\''
> ```

You are wrapping your JSON with single quotes. That makes it invalid JSON. Don't do that.

Comment: That makes it a valid JSON string as far i understood the matter, doesnt it?

Comment: @Markus — No. Not even slightly. Strings in a JSON text must be delimited with `"` not `'`, and your JSON text is clearly supposed to express an object not a string.

Comment: It is typical to wrap JSON in single quotes when writing it as a JavaScript string **literal**, but you aren't doing that. It is coming from an event, not a string literal.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. I got confused during all the string conversions i did. Sorry for the question...